# func is inaccessible due to 'private' protection level

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm trying to migrate my project from iOS 8 to iOS 10 in Xcode 8 using Swift 3. I've encountered an error where in my extension I've declared some file private functions, and the methods within those functions are inaccessible due to private protection level.

Here is where I get the error:

```
extension VideoViewerViewController: SeekerViewDelegate {
fileprivate func seekerViewBeginSeeking(view: SeekerView) {
    self.shouldStartPlayingAfterSeek = self.player.rate > 0.0 //'shouldStartPlayingAfterSeek' is inaccessible due to 'private' protection level
    self.pause() //'pause()' is inaccessible due to 'private' protection level
}
```

This is the protocol that my class is conforming to:

```
private protocol SeekerViewDelegate: class {
func seekerViewBeginSeeking(view: SeekerView)
func seekerView(view: SeekerView, didSeek progress: CGFloat)
func seekerViewDidEndSeeking(view: SeekerView)
}
```

I'm still struggling to grasp the concept of fileprivate, private, and internal.

All help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`internal` is private to the current module. `fileprivate` is private to the current file (which used to be called `private`). The new `private` is private to the current scope (closer to what most people probably think of as private).

Comment: So if I want access to the methods, should I make the protocol fileprivate?

Comment: Yes; otherwise they're limited to the current scope

Comment: Even when I do that, the methods are still inaccessible due to private protection level

Comment: Something above it is marked private. Note that the protocol is private.

Comment: Huh, even making the class fileprivate doesn't seem to be working...the protocol inherits from 'class' so I'm not sure what else above it is marked private

Comment: Ah I feel so dumb...the function itself was marked private..My bad, thank you so much

Comment: what if I want to make it private to the class but declare the extension in a different file?

Comment: @RodrigoRuiz that's not possible to write in Swift today.

Comment: @RodrigoRuiz Your best choice then is to use internal.

Comment: what about if you want to run a test on that portion of the logic - is the only way to make it public? ie I don't want it accessible outside the class - except for the testing.

Comment: @MobileBloke It needs to be at least internal for the tests to see it.